# Elasticsearch query with wildcard and match conditions

Tags: regex, elasticsearch, elasticsearch-query

I have this index:

```
    {
            "mappings": {
                "records" : {
                    "properties" : {
                        "suggest" : {
                            "type" : "completion",
                            "contexts": [
                                { 
                                    "name": "year",
                                    "type": "category",
                                    "path": "year"
                                }
                            ]
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
}
```

I put some records:

```
POST http://localhost:9200/example/records
{
            "suggest": {
                "input": "foo123" ,
                "contexts": {
                    "year": "1999"
                }
            }
}

POST http://localhost:9200/example/records
{
            "suggest": {
                "input": "some123" ,
                "contexts": {
                    "year": "1999"
                }
            }
}
POST http://localhost:9200/example/records
{
            "suggest": {
                "input": "thing123" ,
                "contexts": {
                    "year": "2000"
                }
            }
}
```

Now I would do this query (sql like):

```
SELECT * FROM example WHERE SUGGEST LIKE %123% AND YEAR=1999
```

How can I do in Elastic Search?

I type:

```
    POST http://localhost:9200/example/records/_search?pretty
    {
    "query": {
        "bool": {
            "must": [
                   { "wildcard" : { "suggest" : "*123*" } }

            ], 
            "filter":[
                { "term" : { "year" : "1999" } }
                ]
        }
    }
}
```

I have returned this response with blank results:

```
    {
    "took": 1,
    "timed_out": false,
    "_shards": {
        "total": 5,
        "successful": 5,
        "skipped": 0,
        "failed": 0
    },
    "hits": {
        "total": 0,
        "max_score": null,
        "hits": []
    }
}
```

I am expecting to have returned this records:

- foo123, year 1999
- some123, year 1999

How can I do?

Answer (score 6):

You need to use [bool query](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/master/query-dsl-bool-query.html) with must if you care about score:

```
{
    "query": {
        "bool": {
            "must": [
                { "wildcard" : { "name" : "*foo*" } },
                { "term" : { "year" : "1999" } }
            ]
        }
    }
}
```

or with filter if you just want to filter values and possibly cache the filter:

```
{
    "query": {
        "filter": {
            "must": [
                { "wildcard" : { "name" : "*foo*" } },
                { "term" : { "year" : "1999" } }
            ]
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I think that I am not doing well something...can you see my edited post with the index? @slawek

Comment: You've changed the question completely. Suggest uses different [search API](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/master/search-suggesters-completion.html). I'm not familiar with it enough to help you out. I don't think you can use suggester to do search with multiple conditions, but I could be mistaken.